# 'function' object has no attribute

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code in a file called `task.py`:

```
def train():
    saver_refine = tf.train.Saver(coarse_refine_params)
    saver_refine.restore(sess, refine_ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

I import from `task.py`:

```
from task import train

train.saver_refine.restore(sess, refine_ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

I try to do the above function.

> Error:AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute
>   'saver_refine'

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: `train` is a function. Why are you trying to call attributes on it?

Comment: `train` is function, we can not use as class object.

Comment: Unless I create a class I can not access it right?

Comment: @VivekSable  Functions are instances of the 'function' class. The attributes can be called, but saver_refine is no attribute of train in this example. Try " import types ; isinstance(train, types.FunctionType)"

Comment: Yes, functions are first-class-object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible but usually not useful.

```
def func():
    pass

func.saver_refine = 1
print(func.saver_refine)
```

Accessing local variables from the outside is not possible, they only exist in the namespace of the function while it runs, and they are lost once the function exits.

Comment: it's something seriously wrong with this kind of design though.

Comment: Why? It lives to the object oriented principle that everything is an object.

Comment: although python and javascript are very much look alike. but this is not javascript. maybe if you do `func.prototype.sth = (...)` is good in javascript but in python it definitely means that your design somehow swallowed a class. never do this.